# Can one always convert from Rand5 to Rand7 in finitely many iterations?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that there is a machine (called Rand5) that randomly chooses member of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with uniform distribution. The objective is to use this machine, as many times as we like, to create a new machine (called Rand7) that randomly choose a member of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ with uniform distribution.

There only solution I can think of is to use some form of rejection sampling.

For example, you could use the Rand5 machine twice, yielding $25$ equally likely outcomes. Map $21$ of them to evenly select among the numbers from $1$ to $7$, and then repeat the process if the outcome is not one of these $21$ mapped outcomes.

This solution has the problem that it is not guaranteed to terminate. Is there a solution to the Rand5 to Rand7 problem that is guaranteed to terminate in finitely many steps? If not, can it proven that there is no such solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there is a solution that is guaranteed to terminate. Then there exists some $n$ such that at most $n$ samples of Rand5 are taken (use König's lemma to be precise). Then every path the algorithm takes is taken with a probability a multiple of $\frac1{5^n}$. No sum of such numbers equals $\frac17$ because $7$ does not divide $5^n$, hence there is no proceudre that terminates *for sure*. The best we can get is that it terminates *almost surely* (i.e. with probability $1$); for example by rejection sampling as you describe it; or by interpreting the sequence of Rand5 outputs as the base 5 expansion of a real numbre in $[0,1)$ and stop as soon as it becomes clear in which interval $[\frac k7,\frac{k+1}7)$ we end up.